# How to increase a span's height before its width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a span element inside of a div, that I would like to resize depending on the length of the text inside the span. Basically, the div has a minimum size, but even if the text could fit in it, right now, the span will still increase in width before filling the height available.

I would like the span to fill all available height space before taking more width space. (Think what happens when you resize a text area's width in Paint for example) But I'm not sure how to tell CSS to prioritize height over width.

What the current behavior looks like:
[image: current behavior]

The Behavior I'm trying to achive:
[image: goal]

My code:

```css
.item-drag-handle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  min-height: 25px;
  margin: 3px;
  background-color: white;
}

.item-drag-handle span {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-drag-handle">
        <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="block.contentList">
            <span  *ngIf="item.type === 'text'" >{{item.content}}</span>
            <img   *ngIf="item.type === 'image'" [src]="item.content">
            <video *ngIf="item.type === 'video'" [src]="item.content"></video>
        </ng-template>
</div>
```

Here is an actual screenshot, where you can see different elements side by side:
[image: screenshot]

You can see on the Lorem Ipsum that although there is plenty of available height space, the span still extends the width before filling that space.

Any idea to reach that desired behaviour? I was thinking of using Angular ngClass to manually change the width depending on the text length but that would result in only discrete values for the width (and lots of different classes) so I don't think that's the right way to go.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please use always use a minimal reproduciable code snippet (ctrl + m) to show your code. I already edited your post to move the css into the snippet and added a basic HTML code based on logical assumption. However both HTML and CSS are incomplete to fit your screenshot. As such please edit the snippet further to contain enough code to exactly reproduce the issue.

Comment: There probably aren’t any easy ways to achieve this. The web developed as a “given-width, variable-height” medium, and regarding basics such as text flow, that is still very much “in its bones” today. Maybe hacking that text into individual span elements for each word, and then applying some grid layout properties could get help closer, but I doubt that alone can provide a complete solution either. If anything, I would probably have a closer look at the `table-` display types - tables are the closest thing that provides any such auto-width mechanism.

Comment: left to right text aren't designed to work that way so you are trying to force something to behave against its nature.

Comment: Thank you tacoshy, I completed the code. 
CBroe: I would like to keep the text as a single unit for editing purposes, but I will look into it. Thank you.

Comment: I think you'll need a bit of JS - is that acceptable?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes that is fine. I am using Angular and TypeScript though, so I am not the most proficient with good ol' regular JS.